Extract level data from unknown octet-stream format
Overview:
I wanted to attempt to extract the level data from Happy Wheels, their APIs are all open to pull data. I can pull the data shown in the level lists as well as each individual level ID (it returns all of that in XML) but when I attempt to pull the level data itself (obstacles, guns, etc) it responds with an octet-stream. All of the threads I have pulled told me to read it as hex which I have done but I have no idea where to go from here.
Issue:
POST https://totaljerkface.com/get_level.hw?level_id=1786343&action=get_record&ip_tracking=53445
That API is what the Happy Wheels game hits when it wants to load a new level but it returns it in an unknown format.
My end-goal is to have the level structure data in json or xml format so I can then read it via code.
Other findings:
The way I have been debugging this is, looking at the "Network" tab in my browser as I navigate around the app, for anything level related it always uses /get_level.hw with various parameters to determine the action.
Also when you create a level you can grab the raw levelXml via the UI but after some tinkering I still havent found a way to apply this to other user created levels, only my own and not via API because it still uses the same get_level.hw API with the same response to gather information. But that is good news cause that means all data required is in fact in that response, just have no idea how to decode it or even if thats possible.
Question:
Is it possible to convert the response from get_level.hw to something more readable?
I believe the end format should be what is described here.
It seems it's being decoded in the javascript somewhere but sadly the source map files arent included and I cant find anywhere on github someone posting the decoded source code.
Thanks in advance!
When using a hex viewer, this is what the response of the API looks like.


Did you examine the source code of the response for the embedded game frame (https://totaljerkface.com/happy-wheels-js/index.tjf)? It links to JS files that include lots of hexadecimal indexing operations. I suggest that you start by learning about some basics of reverse engineering and searching for existing questions like the ones in the search results for reverse engineer binary format.

probably contacting the maintainer is the faster way to go xD I mean it seems like you wanted to contribute

This answer shines a light on octet-streams, and beside the Content-Type you'd at least need the Content-Disposition to get a further hint how to handle the data.
Hex-code of some files like PDFs or Images have typical signatures at the beginning or end, this could help too if available, but it doesn't look like the data include a signature.
So essentially you've to know the format or the application that is using the data and find out what the application is doing with it. If the source-code of the game is available you could verify that.
You might get a glimpse by downloading and verifying the JavaScript files of the game-site technically. Be advised that it might infringe some terms of use, especially if made public.
